# Make iOS app compatible on iPhone 4,5,6,6 Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have developed an app for iPhone 5. But when I run it on iPhone 4, lower part is not visible, and when I run it on iPhone 6/6 Plus, it shows only on a part of display, leaving other part white. (Which is logical actually).
So my question is - what should I do to make my iPhone 5 app, to scale up or down depending on device it is install on. Or in other words, how to make it compatible with iPhone 4, 6/6 Plus?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into Adaptive layout features in storyboard.

It helps you place your views according to different sizes and helps you set different sizes for different resolutions.

You can find a helpful tutorial here. [Adaptive layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial)

Comment: Great tutorial. I ll give it a shot!Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways to handle different screen sizes.
The preferred (iOS6 and later) is Auto Layouts

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html